# Including an external library of functions in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a PHP file, which contains two classes and few functions outside these classes.

**I want to know, how do I include/use this file inside my controller/model?**

I don't want to create a separate module and I am a newbie to ZF2.

Comment: Normally library code would side inside the `vendor/` directory. You will need to add it to your auto-loader in order for the files to be found. If you are not already using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) I would recommend it as it will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to have to classes inside the same php file. :|

But if you really just want to use this file, ZF2 is PHP : you can use `require` or `include`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class and your controller can extend from it

File: AsomeFunctions.php (example Application/ExternalLib/AsomeFunctions.php)

```
namespace   Application\ExternalLib;

class AsomeFunctions
{
    //Your Functions, e.g.
    myFunction()
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

File: IndexController.php (in Application/Controller/IndexController.php)

```
//...
use Application/ExternalLib/AsmoeFunctions;
//...
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController, AsomeFunctions
{
  //...
  AsomeFunctions::myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `require '../vendor/yourLibrary/yourFile.php';` in the index file.